# Marking tables as equations

Tags: tables, labels

I have to create table as on the picture. I have done everything exept assigning names *(c)* and *(d)* to the tables. I have a ssugestion to create an additional column to the table and put the letters there. But I think it's not the same as on the picture. Probably there is more correct way to do that?

[image: Needed table]

```
\begin{table}[h]

\centering
\begin{tabular}[c]{l*{5}{r}}    
    \hline
Color     & White & Red & Green & Blue & Yellow \\ \hline
Chance \% & 90    & 6   & 1     & 1    & 2      \\
Prize \$  & 0     & 45  & 30    & -15  & -15 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

and

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering

\begin{tabular}[c]{l*{5}{r}}    
    \hline
    Color     & White & Red & Green & Blue & Yellow \\ \hline
    Chance \% & 90    & 6   & 1     & 1    & 2      \\
    Prize \$  & 0     & 45  & 45    & -10  & -15 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  You should indent code 4 spaces to highlight it.  These look more like subfigure labels than equation labels to me.   Have you tried look at the [`subcaption` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption?lang=en) or one of the other related packages?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about it as caption! Thank you

Comment: As far a LaTeX is concerned, a tabular is no different than a single word in a line of text.  The only question is alignment and spacing.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want it to work like an equation (albeit with letters on the left side instead of numbers on either the right or left):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{showframe}% MWE only

\newcounter{mytable}
\renewcommand{\themytable}{(\Alph{mytable})}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{mytable}[2][c]% same as tabular
{\refstepcounter{mytable}%
 \begin{trivlist}%
   \@beginparpenalty\predisplaypenalty  
   \@endparpenalty\postdisplaypenalty
   \item[]\leavevmode\rlap{\themytable}\hfil
     \begin{tabular}[#1]{#2}\BODY\end{tabular}\hfil
 \end{trivlist}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Preceeding sentence
\begin{mytable}[c]{l*{5}{r}}    
    \hline
Color     & White & Red & Green & Blue & Yellow \\ \hline
Chance \% & 90    & 6   & 1     & 1    & 2      \\
Prize \$  & 0     & 45  & 30    & -15  & -15 \\ \hline
\end{mytable}
and
\begin{mytable}[c]{l*{5}{r}}    
    \hline
    Color     & White & Red & Green & Blue & Yellow \\ \hline
    Chance \% & 90    & 6   & 1     & 1    & 2      \\
    Prize \$  & 0     & 45  & 45    & -10  & -15 \\ \hline
\end{mytable}
so there.

\end{document}
```

[image]